# How can I retrieve values that was posted to a Visualforce page?

Tags: apex

In a page controller, I can get hold of values that was passed to the page via GET (the URL query string parameters) like this:

```
String theId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
```

How do I get hold of values that was passed to the page via POST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you should also just be able to get the post parameters with the getParameters function.

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Re-Get-POST-data-via-visualforce-page/td-p/104987

Comment: Good find! Thank you very much. Just to add for others: I didn't experience the "true url" problem that is mentioned in the referenced article